# How to create Fully adjacent layer in a GCN with Pytorch

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, pytorch-geometric, graph-neural-network

1. I would like to implement a GNN network with a fully adjacent final layer, which means to say all nodes of the final graph are connected to all other nodes.
2. It is similiar to as mentioned in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.05205)
3. I am currently using Pytorch Geometric as shown here:

```
    self.conv1 = GCNConv(num_node_features, 16)
    self.conv2 = GCNConv(16, 16)
    self.conv3 = GCNConv(16, 16)
    self.conv4 = GCNConv(16, num_classes)
```

How can I make conv4 to be fully adjacent?

Comment: The adjacency matrix is determined by the edge list. In other words, if two nodes are far from each other and they do not have any nearby neighbors, then they will not be connected, and thus the adjacency matrix cannot be "fully" connected. Overall, this is a trade-off between higher-order neighbors and GNN depth: if your GNN is deep enough, you will eventually reach to a fully connected adjacency matrix.